# JavaFX 8: Changing title of primary stage

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

How can the title of the primary stage be changed, when the window is already showen?

`Stage#setTitle(String)` apparently does not the trick.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`setTitle(...)` seems to work fine here:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class UpdateStageTitle extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        TextField titleField = new TextField();
        titleField.textProperty().addListener((obs, oldText, newText) -> 
            primaryStage.setTitle(newText));
        HBox root = new HBox(5, new Label("Window title: "), titleField);
        root.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 350, 75);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

**Update** following comments.

For a more complex example, if you need to set this in the controller's initialize method, you need to arrange for the controller to have a reference to the stage before the `FXMLLoader`'s `load()` method is invoked. You can do this either by calling `setController` on the loader, or by calling `setControllerFactory`. I generally prefer setting the controller factory, as it allows for use of the `fx:controller` attribute in FXML (setting the controller directly prohibits this).

So:

PrimaryStageAware.java:

```
package application;

import javafx.stage.Stage;

public interface PrimaryStageAware {
    public void setPrimaryStage(Stage primaryStage);
}
```

Main.java:

```
package application;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;


public class Main extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        try {
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("TitleSetter.fxml"));
            loader.setControllerFactory((Class<?> type) -> {
                try {
                    Object controller = type.newInstance();
                    if (controller instanceof PrimaryStageAware) {
                        ((PrimaryStageAware) controller).setPrimaryStage(primaryStage);
                    }
                    return controller ;
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(e);
                }
            });
            HBox root = loader.load();
            Scene scene = new Scene(root,400,400);
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

TitleSetter.fxml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.layout.HBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>

<HBox alignment="CENTER" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" 
    fx:controller="application.TitleSettingController">
    <Label text="Update title: "/>
    <TextField  fx:id="titleField" />
</HBox>
```

TitleSettingController.java:

```
package application;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class TitleSettingController implements PrimaryStageAware {
    private Stage stage ;

    @FXML
    private TextField titleField ;

    @Override
    public void setPrimaryStage(Stage primaryStage) {
        this.stage = primaryStage ;
    }

    public void initialize()  {
        updateTitle("Initial title");
        titleField.textProperty().addListener((obs, oldTitle, newTitle) -> updateTitle(newTitle));
    }

    private void updateTitle(String title) {
        if (stage != null) {
            stage.setTitle(title);
        } else {
            System.out.println("Warning: null stage");
        }
    }

}
```

(With the FXML in the same package alongside the Java files).

Comment: Your code works here as well, apparently the #setTitle(String) has no effect if called in the initialize method of a controller ...

Comment: How are you getting a reference to the window in the initialize method of the controller?

Comment: @Janes_D I extended FXMLLoader to pass the reference of the primary stage to the controller: http://pastebin.com/UuHTvBui

Comment: Updated with an example that works (all your structure except Spring).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63438/discussion-between-hannes-and-james-d).

Answer (score 2):

I worked this out using FXML. This would be my simple interface `ChangeTitle.fxml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>

<AnchorPane fx:controller="ChangeTitleController" prefHeight="117.0" prefWidth="198.0" 
            xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.65">
   <children>
      <TextField fx:id="input" layoutX="16.0" layoutY="32.0" onAction="#doStuff" />
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Notice The `fx:controller=` directive that tells FXML which class to use as controller. Also notice That the TextField `input` has an onAction directive that tells FXML to run `doStuff()` as actionHandler.

Now this is the class that starts the application `ChangeTitle.class`:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class ChangeTitle extends Application {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
  }

  @Override
  public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("ChangeTitle.fxml"));

    Scene scene = new Scene(root);
    primaryStage.setTitle("Change me");

    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
  }

}
```

And finally we have a controller to do the actual work `ChangeTitleController.class`. We use `Stage primStage = (Stage) input.getScene().getWindow();` within the `doStuff()` method to get a handle on the primary stage.

```
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class ChangeTitleController implements Initializable {

  @FXML private TextField input;

  @Override
  public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {

  }

  @FXML private void doStuff() {
    Stage primStage = (Stage) input.getScene().getWindow();
    primStage.setTitle(input.getText());

  }

}
```

Comment: That solution is the simplest, the current accepted solution might be overkill in a lot of cases.

Answer (score 2):

You can make Main class as singleton and to contact him via Main.getInstance()

For example:

```
public class Main extends Application {

    private static Main instance;
    public static Main getInstance() {
        return instance;
    }

    private Stage primaryStage;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
        instance = this;
        this.primaryStage = primaryStage;
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("main.fxml"));
        this.primaryStage.setTitle("Init title");
        this.primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 900, 650));
        this.primaryStage.show();
        FlatterFX.style();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    public void updateTitle(String title) {
        primaryStage.setTitle(title);
    }
}
```